# Single file upload using PLupload?

Tags: javascript, jquery, plupload, ajax-upload

We have another library we use for doing ajax uploads of images, which does some other processing for us.

We are attempting to model plupload to use the same UI. This is working well, but I am stuck on one part. the other uploader sticks a start button next to each item. allowing us to individually upload specific items in the list.

Does PLupload have the ability to upload a specific item from the list?

Comment: plupload allows you to write your own UI, so you are not limited to the default "upload queue". For example: http://www.plupload.com/example_custom.php You'll have to code it yourself, but the tools are certainly there to do whatever you want.

Comment: Yes I have created the UI, but there does not seem to be a way to tell the core api to only upload the individual file once it is added to the queue. e.g. there is `uploader.removeFile(file)` but there does not seem to be `uploader.uploadFile(file)` or `uploader.start(file)`.

Comment: Why not list the files the user selects (via custom script), but only add one of them to the queue? I'd answer with a demo, but I shouldn't even be on SO right now - I've got work to do... but post your current plupload script.

Comment: Because When selecting files via the PLuploader API it automatically adds them to the queue, I don't think there is any way to grab hold of the raw file handler, otherwise I would have done that :/ Good suggestion though I thought the same thing!

Comment: Don't know if it's possible. Maybe you can do something by trying to put the desired file at the beginning of the queue (by splice() the queue, and adding the returned spliced files at the end of the files array). Then you could start() the uploader, and stop() it beforeupload() of the next file. But, I'm afraid, in terms of UX, it would be ugly.

Answer (score 0):

You can create new instances of the Uploader and swap around entries from their files arrays.  Using this technique I'm able to do things like serialize the uploads.  For that, I pop each file off the main uploader's files array and make a new uploader and push that file into its files array (and then invoke the send on that ad hoc uploader with the one file in it).  For drag and drop I had to make a new uploader to receive the drop but then I take its file and put it in the master uploader instance.